# Is it possible to wget using credentials?

Tags: ssh, wget

Suppose I want to wget s file from a site but that site requires me to login first to download file. So is it possible to login on that server/site using SSH and wgeting that file from that logged user account? Or is it insane?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible/easy to use wget to do what you ask. I imagine what you're looking for Secure Copy (SCP). You can use SCP as follows:

scp user@host:/path/to/file /destination/file.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy or http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp

Comment: I wanna import a file from xyz.com
It requires us to login to access site.
if i login, the file is in xyz.com/user/file/dl/?hash=1234

can it be done (imported) via scp or ssh? :)

Comment: Yes, you can do that with scp. scp (whatever your username is)@xyz.com/user/file/dl/?hash=1234 /(path on your local machine)

This will prompt you to authenticate with your password, then will proceed to copy the file to whatever location you specified.

Comment: I did this-
scp ashtm@https://xyz.com/go/content/f/id/21 but got output:
usage: scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 [...] [[user@]host2:]file2

Comment: Sorry, typo from me in the previous comment. The syntax is as I posted in the original answer. Make sure to use ':' after the domain. 'scp ashtm@xyz.com:go/content/f/id/21 .' without the quotes, where the '.' is your current directory. You can change to other directories by specifying